# CSV Type Provider cannot find column in F# interactive

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-interactive, f#-data

So let's say I have a CSV file with a header containing columns Population and Profit, and I'd like to work with it in F# interactive. I have the following code:

```
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.1.1.10/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"

open FSharp.Data

// load csv header
let cities = new CsvProvider<"cities.csv">()

// how to reach data
let firstRow = cities.Data |> Seq.head
let firstPopulation = firstRow.Population
let firstProfit = firstRow.Profit
```

I get an error from F# interactive:

> error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Population' is not defined

This seems confusing to me, because intellisense in VS has no problem picking up this column from my data via a CSV type provider.

Also, I tried creating a program with the same type provider and it all works just fine. Like this:

```
open FSharp.Data

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    use file = System.IO.File.CreateText("result.txt")
    let csv = new CsvProvider<"cities.csv">()
    for record in csv.Data do
        fprintfn file "%A" record.Population
    0
```

Am I missing something? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Can you try using full path to the CSV file? (Sometimes F# Interactive gets confused about paths...)

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure you've sent all the lines to fsi? I just tried something similar an it worked. What version of VS are you using?

Comment: If there was a problem with the path it would give an explicit error, unless by change there's a cities.csv somewhere else without that Population column

Comment: This scenario may take place if you first named your column say `xyzzy`, locked the TP to FSI session by an attempt to execute, then renamed column to `Population` and tried executing again within the same FSI session. Then instance of TP within VS (and Intellisense) would be aware of property name change, but FSI-bound one  wouldn't. Try resetting FSI session and repeat attempt to run.

Comment: Tomas, I have changed path to full path and it starts work. Also Gene you are right It was different column name in the first place.

Comment: @GustavoGuerra I think I've seen this behavior before - but only during a live talk so did not have much time to debug :-). Not sure what is going on...

Comment: Was the change to the csv file done inside or outside VS? Maybe this is related to https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/pull/283 so might be already fixed?

Comment: @GustavoGuerra I create csv file inside VS.

Comment: The same thing just happened to me. I created the CsvProvider using a relative path and then loaded using the full path. Once I used the full path for both it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
let Cities = new CsvProvider<"cities.csv">()
let cities = new Cities()
let firstRow = cities.Rows |> Seq.head
```